# A question about iterated integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

In a circumstance I had to show that
$$
\int_0^t \int_0^x \int_0^y f(z)\,dz\,dy\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f(z)(t-z)^2 \,dz
$$
, where $t$ is a constant.

I succeeded in doing so by integration by parts. I let
$$
\int f(x) \,dx = F(x),\quad \int F(x)\,dx = \varphi(x),\quad \int \varphi(x)\, dx = \phi(x)
$$
and parse $\int_0^t f(z)(t-z)^2 \,dz$ by $\int_0^t (t-z)^2 \,d(F(z)) = \left.F(z)(t-z)^2\right|_0^t - \int F(z)\, d(t-z)^2$ and so on... Then, I evaluated the integral $\int_0^t \int_0^x \int_0^y f(z)\,dz\,dy\,dz$ and confirmed that their results were equal.

Yet this method was obviously not simple. Since that I encountered this problem in my multivariable calculus studying, I wonder if there is a geometry approach or something more multivariable to this...

I noticed by the integration limits that the region on which $f(z)$ is being integrated seems to be
$$
\{(x,y,z): 0 \leq z \leq y \wedge 0 \leq y \leq x \wedge 0 \leq x \leq t\}
$$
But I can't conclude anything on this because I know nothing about $f(z)$...

Comment: Are these Riemann or Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: Have you considered interchanging the order of integration?

Comment: @Vajra This appears in my multivariable calculus courses so I suppose the integrals are Riemann

Comment: You can write your triple integral as $$\int_0^t \int_z^t \int_y^tf(z)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$$

Comment: @GuanyumingHe I hope you are clear how you would change the order of integral to either $dx \ dy \ dz$ or $dy \ dx \ dz$. As $f(z)$ is only a function of $z$, the two inner integrals can be easily evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments, I now understand that change the order of integration is more convenient.